# Reference book on spectral clustering

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, clustering

Can someone recommend a reference book that deals with spectral clustering?
It seems to me that the literature in the subject is poor.

Answer (score 2):

I learned a lot from Piet van Mieghems book "Graph Spectra for Complex Networks" from 2010.

Comment: I'd suggest you add a bit more about what you liked about this book in your answer.